# SQL Update Table Based On Data From Another Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to update a table in one database with information from another table in a different database. On top of that I need a third table to establish the link between the two. Here's what I have:

```
Update
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers]
Set
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientOccupation] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field3)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmploymentStatusCode] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field4)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmploymentFromDate] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field5)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmploymentThruDate] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field6)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerPhoneNumber] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field7)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientNationalEmployerID] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field8)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerName] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field9)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerAddress1] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field11)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerAddress2] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field12)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerCity] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field13)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerStateCode] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field15)),
MT.dbo.[tblPatientEmployers].[PatientEmployerZipCode] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field16))
from [MT_Work].[dbo].[impHL7Xref] as T
inner join [MT_Work].[dbo].[impHL7Xref] 
   ON MT.dbo.tblPatients.[MedicalRecordNumber] = [MT_Work].[dbo].[impHL7Xref].MRN
WHERE T.RecordType = 'PATEMP'
```

Which results in the error message:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The multi-part identifier "MT.dbo.tblPatients.MedicalRecordNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: You don't have `tblPatients` listed as a table you're pulling from.  You need to `Join` to it before you can reference it.

Comment: That table is neither in your update or from clause.  The fact that you are using more than one database is not relevent.

Comment: You are using `[MT_Work].[dbo].[impHL7Xref]` twice and not using `MT.dbo.tblPatients`. How are your 3 tables really related?

Comment: The tables are related as impHL7Xref.MRN = tblPatients.MedicalRecordNumber and tblPatients.ID = tblPatientEmployers.PatientID if that makes sense.

Comment: One hint that might have helped you get answers to your question is to [use the "@" sign to respond to specific people in the comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). This notifies them that you've answered their question (so, for example, @Lamak asked for the relationship between the three tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have never told SQL Server how your tables are all related. You need each table in the FROM clause in order to make this work: next time you write an UPDATE statement, try first writing a SELECT statement that pulls all the values you want and displays them.  This will help you ensure you have the correct connections.

Assuming I'm reading your conditions right, you're looking for the following:

```
UPDATE PE
SET
    PE.[PatientOccupation] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field3)),
    PE.[PatientEmploymentStatusCode] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field4)),
    PE.[PatientEmploymentFromDate] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field5)),
    PE.[PatientEmploymentThruDate] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field6)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerPhoneNumber] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field7)),
    PE.[PatientNationalEmployerID] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field8)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerName] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field9)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerAddress1] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field11)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerAddress2] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field12)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerCity] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field13)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerStateCode] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field15)),
    PE.[PatientEmployerZipCode] = RTRIM(LTRIM(T.Field16))
FROM 
    [MT_Work].[dbo].[impHL7Xref] T
     INNER JOIN 
    MT.dbo.tblPatients P ON 
        T.MRN = P.MedicalRecordNumber
     INNER JOIN 
    MT.dbo.tblPatientEmployers PE ON 
        P.ID = PE.PatientID
WHERE T.RecordType = 'PATEMP'
```